# Cual es la diferencia entre align item y text align?

Tags: css

Para poner en contexto, puse dos elemento `<DIV>` que dentro de cada uno tenian un `<H3>,<IMG>,<P>` por lo que puse el elemento padre en **DISPLAY:FLEX**, y luego queria que los elementos hijos queden centrados, le puse la **flex-direction: column** y posterior use ***ALIGN-ITEMS: CENTER;*** y solo las imagenes, y un `<H3>` se puso centrado y el otro `<h3>` y los `<P>` de los dos elementos padres no se puso centrado, mi pregunta es: a que se debe eso?

posteriormente, puse un TEXT-align: center y de ahi, ya todo se quedo centrado, pero mi pregunta en esencia es: Si un `<H3>` de un elemento padre, ya se centro, por que el otro no?

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte

Answer (score 3):

Esencialmente la diferencia es que **align-items** centra todos los descendientes o por decirlo de otro modo los hijos directos. Sin embargo esta alineación es *vertical*.

En cambio **text-align** centra textos de forma *horizontal*.

Sería ideal que subieras tu código donde realizas esta parte para poder responder específicamente.

Enlaces de interés relacionados:

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.ASP
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/align-items